# D3.js Unable to get map zooming to work in Webkit browsers

Tags: d3.js, webkit

I have a map where clicking an area to zoom in works in FireFox, but not in Chrome, Opera and Safari.
The map can be viewed at http://tcan.ca/content/tcan-neighbourhood-members

Anyone have suggestions about what can be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use transformations directly on the `<svg>` element in webkit -- and even on other browsers, it won't always do what you expect.

A top-level `<svg>` element is positioned on the webpage as an HTML object (similar to a `<div>`).  Transformations that apply to it are interpretted as HTML/CSS transformations.  The CSS transformation syntax is still not finalized and webkit browsers only support a prefixed `-webkit-transform` version.

Rather than deal with multiple transformation syntaxes, add a `<g>` element inside your `<svg>`, append all your graphical content within the `<g>`, and then declare your SVG transformations on the `<g>`.  It will work in all the browsers that support SVG.

Comment: I had read that using a group might fix this problem but so far no luck. I probably positioned the group definition incorrectly. If you can spare the time please look at http://jsfiddle.net/PatriciaW/CnLT2/ and let me know what mistake is.

Comment: You were correctly adding the `<g>` element and adding the content to it, but your event handling functions were still applying the transforms on the `<svg>`.  Here's a working version of your fiddle with those changes made for the path click and reset functions (you may have to make similar changes on functions related to your circle points, I didn't check that code carefully): http://jsfiddle.net/CnLT2/1/

Comment: Wonderful. At first when I tested it the circles did not zoom with the map but I managed to figure it out and now it is functioning correctly on FF and Chrome. - Many thanks.